# Creating a group of instances by name AutoFac

Tags: c#, autofac

Assuming that i have this class:

```
public class ProcessObject : IProcessObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ProcessObject(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
public interface IProcessObject
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using AutoFac as IoC-Container I need to be able to retreive unique instances of this class by the property Name.

If a processobject of a certain name has already been created, i would like to return that specific instance.

"Sample code of usage"

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ProcessObject>();
builder.RegisterType<ProcessObject>().As<IProcessObject>().;
Container = builder.Build();
var obj1 = Container.Resolve<IProcessObject>(new NamedParameter("Name", "UniqueObjectByName1"));//Does not exist, create new instance
var obj2 = Container.Resolve<IProcessObject>(new NamedParameter("Name", "UniqueObjectByName1"));//An instance with this name exists, return that instance
var obj3 = Container.Resolve<IProcessObject>(new NamedParameter("Name", "UniqueObjectByName2"));//Does not exist, create new instance
Debug.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj2));//this is currently returning False, I would like it to be true
Debug.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj3));
```

In my current code i maintain this principles by having a static method in ProcessObject class and singleton list for keeping track of all my ProcessObjects.

```
public static GetInstance(string Name)
{
    if (ProcessObjects.GetInstanceByName(Name) == null)
    {
        return new ProcessObject(Name);
    }
    else return ProcessObjects.GetInstanceByName(Name);
}
```

Do I still need this, or does AutoFac offer a solution to return unique instances by a value of a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac doesn't allow you to name objects or add metadata on the fly, so you'll still need your factory method that caches the instances by name.

However, you could tie that factory into Autofac so it *seems* like it caches by name:

```
// Let's say your factory is like this, where the cache
// is stored in the instance, like a hash table. Adjust
// your code as necessary.
builder.RegisterType<MyCachingFactory>()
  .As<IFactory>()
  .SingleInstance();

// Register a lambda that looks at the inbound set
// of parameters and uses the registered factory
// to resolve.
builder.Register((c, p) =>
{
  var name = p.Named<string>("Name");
  var factory = c.Resolve<IFactory>();
  return factory.GetInstanceByName(name);
}).As<IProcessObject>();
```

Doing that, you should be able to do what you're looking for:

```
container.Resolve<IProcessObject>(new NamedParameter("Name", "a"));
```

Comment: Awesome solution! I have just one question, will the method in your sample "factory.GetInstanceByName(name);" be the same as my old method "GetInstance(string Name)"? Or would you change that as well?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the body of your factory method at the time, didn't realize it was named differently. It doesn't matter what you call it, the intent is the same.